# not needed inactive picklist value

Tags: picklist

below code is fetching all the picklist values of status field (case object). i want only active picklist values how it is possible.

```
   caseStatuslist = new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =  Case.Status.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

   for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
      caseStatuslist.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `isActive()` function on the [PicklistEntry](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.html) class.

For example, in your `for` loop you can check each iteration to see if it's active:

```
for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
  if (f.isActive()) {
    caseStatuslist.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
  }
}
```

As mentioned in the docs, this function returns a Boolean that:

> Returns true if this item must be displayed in the drop-down list for the picklist field in the user interface, false otherwise.